# clarification of definition of immersed and embedded submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

let $F:M \to N$ be an injective immersion.Then,$F:M \to F(M)$ is a bijection and we can use it to give a topology on $F(M)$.Also,we know that every immersion is a local embedding.So,$F$ is a bijective map onto $F(M)$ which is also a local homeomorphism $\Rightarrow$F is a homeomorphism M onto $F(M)$.using this,homeomorphism,we can get differentiable atlas on $F(M)$ and hence $F(M)$ is called immersed submanifold.

My problem is:

"Suppose i give $F(M)$ subspace topology ,where,$F$ is injective immersion.Then,again $F$ becomes local homeomorphism+bijection onto $F(M)\Rightarrow$$F$ is a homeomorphism,but this is not so (counterexample:figure eight)".

where am i getting this wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An injective immersion of a compact smooth manifold is an embedding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics).

If the domain is non-compact then we need to add the condition that the injective immersion gives a homeomorphism $f: M \rightarrow f(M)$, where the topology on $f(M)$ is the sub-space topology inherited from $N$. In general, this will be different from the topology you described in the second sentence, and this is the source of confusion.

This is exactly the situation with the injective immersion $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ parametrising the figure of eight figure. This is not a homeomorphism to its image (since for example the figure of eight is not simply connected), hence is not a smooth embedding. Note this is a bijective, local homeomorphism but it is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: :isn't f(M) itself the range of f??even if i give f(M) subspace topology from N,injective immersion need not be an embedding

Comment: $N$ is the range of $f$ I was reffering to, I changed my answer to make this clear. Yes it is true that an injective immersion need not be an embedding.

Comment: :thanks for your reply.i get what you are saying must hold for defining embedded submanifolds."is the condition of injective immersion sufficient to define immersed submanifolds",i think this is is true because the topology given to f(M) using bijection ensures that $f^-1$ becomes continuous and hence f:M$\to$F(M) becomes a homeomorphism